# PDF Generation: Classic Email Template Content is counted in Salesforce Apex Code Limit?

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

We need to send PDF based on salesforce record. For this we have used Classic Email Template and Messaging.Singleemailmessage class to send PDF as attachment. We have used custom template for formatted PDF.

We have added around 280 lines of template code. Are these lines of code (Email Template) are counted in Apex Limit?

Comment: Governor limits (e.g. CPU time), or number of characters limit?

Comment: number of characters limit for our org.